# .htaccess Mod_Rewrite for multiple conditions

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following URLs that I'm struggling to rewrite in the .htaccess file in my domain root. At best, I get a 500 Server Error.

From: http://sub.example.com/a/?id=1234
To: http://sub.example.com/a/1234

From: http://sub.example.com/a/b/?id=1234
To: http://sub.example.com/a/1234/b

From what I've read it should be fairly straightforward, but I can't seem to get anything to work!

Comment: So far, variations on the below have been unsuccessful:
RewriteEngine On   ::   
RewriteRule ^a/(.*) /a/?id=$1 [NC]

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^a/([0-9]+)(/.*)?$ /a$2/?id=$1 [NC]
```